# Unable to create C# windows application as installable file along with a word file which is acting as template

Tags: c#, windows, ms-word, windows-installer

I have a windows application which try to convert to installable file. I know that there is lot of ways to convert my application as a installable(Visual Studio installer, setup and deployment etc).

My problem is, I also have a word file which is acting like a template file. Where some from the form will get copied to that template file whenever i click copy.

When I tried to create a exe file via "Visual studio installer(Setup project)" via visual stuido 2015 I end up with "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I'm novice on visual studio since i learnt things from various sources converting winforms to installable files.

IDE: Visual studio 2015 (set up and deployment)
C# Application

I expect to copy things from win form to a word file after converting my application as a installable file.

************* Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

string afterbin = "";
 const string MyFileName = @"Documents\ballot_sheet2.docx";

```
                string execPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
                //The below one is included to redirect the path to documents folder under my project. By default it picks bin folder
                int pos = execPath.IndexOf(@"\bin\Debug");
                if (pos >= 0)
                {
                    afterbin = execPath.Remove(pos);
                }
                var filePath = Path.Combine(afterbin, MyFileName);

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = null;
                app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

                doc = app.Documents.Open(filePath);
```

Comment: without seeing the code it's impossible to even begin to guess what the problem might be...

Comment: The problem is, "When i run from my visual studio the code works perfectly fine with no errors",only when i try to convert into installable file the error occurs. Do you still wanted my code here?

Comment: The relevant part is how the code is working with the Word file / initializing whatever objects in the code that work with the Word file. The code should definitely included the line(s) that cause the error. My inclination would be that the code isn't finding the template/file, so can't initialize, but then I'd expect an error to the effect that the file can't be found...

Comment: @CindyMeister Have added the code. Do you suspect anything wrong here?

Comment: Log that path so that you can see exactly what it's using to try to open the document. Then see if the document is actually there. Also, check whether the project has the necessary *permissions* to access that location.

Comment: @CindyMeister This is something that works. Have found out the actual path (which is C:\ProgramFiles\MyProject\Documents) where the file required is been missing. Agreeing how introducing logger will give helping hands. :) Thank you Cindy